# converting data frame (factors) into xts

Tags: r, dataframe, xts, performanceanalytics

I know this have been asked several times but I could not find the right way to get around my problem. I have a very simple CSV file that I upload, looking like:

```
27.07.2015,100
28.07.2015,100.1504
29.07.2015,100.1957
30.07.2015,100.5044
31.07.2015,100.7661
03.08.2015,100.9308
04.08.2015,100.8114
05.08.2015,100.6927
06.08.2015,100.7501
07.08.2015,100.7194
10.08.2015,100.8197
11.08.2015,100.8133
```

Now I need to convert my data.frame into xts so I can use the PerformanceAnalytics package. My data.frame has the structure:

```
> str(mpey)
'data.frame':   243 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ V1: Factor w/ 243 levels "01.01.2016","01.02.2016",..: 210 218 228 234 241 21 30 38 45 52 ...
   - attr(*, "names")= chr  "5" "6" "7" "8" ...
 $ V2: Factor w/ 242 levels "100","100.0062",..: 1 4 5 10 16 20 17 13 15 14 ...
   - attr(*, "names")= chr  "5" "6" "7" "8" ...
```

I tried different things with `as.xts` function but could make it work.
Could you please help me get over this?

Comment: V1 is a factor, maybe change it to character or date class? And V2 is factor, maybe you might need to change it to numeric.

Comment: already tried, but I can't. it always give me ***  as.Date.factor(mpey[,1])
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format or if I try ***
> as.Date(mpey[,1])
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: When I add the format = "%d/%m/%Y", i get 252 NA rows.....

Comment: Adding `format = "%d/%m/%Y"` won't work because your dates aren't like `"27/07/2015"`.  Use `format = "%d.%m.%Y"`.  And something is wrong with your `V2` data if `read.table` converts it to factor. You need to look at the raw CSV for a non-numeric character in that column. You could start by converting `V2` to numeric in R and finding the row(s) that are coerced to `NA` because they can't be converted to a number.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using the `tidyquant` package, which contains `as_xts()` for coercing data frames to xts objects and `as_tibble()` for coercing time series objects such as xts to tibbles ("tidy" data frames).

Recreate your data

```
> data_df
# A tibble: 12 × 2
         date    value
       <fctr>   <fctr>
1  27.07.2015      100
2  28.07.2015 100.1504
3  29.07.2015 100.1957
4  30.07.2015 100.5044
5  31.07.2015 100.7661
6  03.08.2015 100.9308
7  04.08.2015 100.8114
8  05.08.2015 100.6927
9  06.08.2015 100.7501
10 07.08.2015 100.7194
11 10.08.2015 100.8197
12 11.08.2015 100.8133
```

First, we need to reformat your data frame. The dates and values are both stored as factors and they need to be in a date and double class, respectively. We'll load `tidyquant` and reformat the data frame. Note that `tidyquant` loads the `tidyverse` and financial packages so you don't need to load anything else. The date can be converted with `lubridate::dmy` which converts characters in a day-month-year format to date. The value needs to go from factor to character then from character to double, and this is done by nesting `as.numeric` and `as.character`.

```
> library(tidyquant)
> data_tib <- data_df %>%
     mutate(date = dmy(date),
            value = as.numeric(as.character(value)))
> data_tib
# A tibble: 12 × 2
         date    value
       <date>    <dbl>
1  2015-07-27 100.0000
2  2015-07-28 100.1504
3  2015-07-29 100.1957
4  2015-07-30 100.5044
5  2015-07-31 100.7661
6  2015-08-03 100.9308
7  2015-08-04 100.8114
8  2015-08-05 100.6927
9  2015-08-06 100.7501
10 2015-08-07 100.7194
11 2015-08-10 100.8197
12 2015-08-11 100.8133
```

Now, we can coerce to `xts` using the `tidyquant::as_xts()` function. Just specify `date_col = date`.

```
> data_xts <- data_tib %>%
     as_xts(date_col = date)
> data_xts
              value
2015-07-27 100.0000
2015-07-28 100.1504
2015-07-29 100.1957
2015-07-30 100.5044
2015-07-31 100.7661
2015-08-03 100.9308
2015-08-04 100.8114
2015-08-05 100.6927
2015-08-06 100.7501
2015-08-07 100.7194
2015-08-10 100.8197
2015-08-11 100.8133
```